# Chamando função do VUE atraves de outro Iframe

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2, vuex

Pessoal fiz um formulario onde é executado uma acão em iframe,
eu preciso que de alguma forma, esse arquivo que estou abrindo no iframe chame minha função em VUE, estou postando meu codigo abaixo.

```
new Vue({
el:"#app",

data : {  
teste : '',
},

methods :{ 

salvar : function(){
this.$refs.form.submit();
},

retorno : function(){
alert('esse é o retorno')
}

}});
```

Código externo:

```
<script>
  parent.retorno();
</script>
```

Comment: Ambos a página mãe e a iframe estão no mesmo domínio?

Comment: sim, estão no mesmo dominio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode usar o postMessage, exemplo:

```
iframe - > 

    function handleButtonClick(e) {
      window.parent.postMessage('iframe_message')
    }

página - >

window.addEventListener('iframe_message', function() {
  console.log("chamar função");
}, false);
```